# Reset IntelliJ UI to Default

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm evaluating the IntelliJ IDE. I changed some of the display/font setting (among other things) and would like to reset the UI back to default. Is there a simple way to reset the display UI back to its default settings?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**Recent Versions**

`Window -> Restore Default Layout`

(Thanks to [Seven4X's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841094/294657))

**Older Versions**

You can simply delete the whole configuration folder `${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea60/config` while IntelliJ IDEA is not running. Next time it restarts, everything is restored from the default settings.

It depends on the OS:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108

Comment: your key file is in this directory ( pycharm50.key ) for me ; you may need to keep that .

Comment: As of 2017, [the answer by Seven4X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841094/294657) is the correct one.

Comment: I don't see "Resotre Default Layout" in 2023.1.4, only "Restore Current Layout".

Answer (score 44):

On Mac OS for IntelliJ v12, shut down the IDE, and then you can execute:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC12/*
```

Restart the IDE, or open a pom.xml of your choosing. You will be asked whether you want to import the preferences from an existing IntelliJ instance. Select the "No, I do not have a previous IntelliJ version" radio button.

Comment: also rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/IdeaIC12; rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/IdeaIC12; rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/IdeaIC12; as in http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181 updated for new version paths

Answer (score 22):

You can [delete IDEA configuration directory](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) to reset everything to the defaults. If you want to reset the editor Colors&Fonts, then just switch the scheme to Default.

Comment: It does not work, at least in IDEA 13.1 Ultimate. That is why the question appears at all.

Answer (score 14):

All above answers are correct, but you loose configuration settings.

But if your IDE's only themes or fonts are changed or some UI related issues and you want to restore to default theme, then just delete

***${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea13/config/options/options.xml***

file while IDE is not running, then after next restart IDE's theme will gets reset to default.

Comment: On my system (Linux, IntelliJ14) removing the options.xml was not enough. Parts of the UI still were messed up. I also had to remove colors.scheme.xml and laf.xml before everything was back with the default style.

Comment: +1. I accidentally `rm -rf` my options folder when trying to view the contents then the SDK setup is gone. All java entities are highlighted as errors. I have to reconfigure it. So do be careful not to remove the whole folder. Just rm the xml file instead. BTW the path is `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14/options/options.xml` for Idea 14

Comment: In the most recent edition, delete colors.xml. Options.xml will not affect color settings. You may need to switch themes as well to see the change.

Answer (score 11):

To switch between color schemes: Choose View -> Quick Switch Scheme on the main menu or press Ctrl+Back Quote
To bring back the old theme: Settings -> Appearance -> Theme

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers are outdated. This is now doable from the menu:

Window -> Restore Default Layout (shift+f12)

Make sure nothing is currently running, as the Run/Debug window layout will not be reset otherwise.

Comment: Be sure to restart intellij after running this

Answer (score 6):

From the main **menu**, select **File** | **Manage IDE Settings** | **Restore Default Settings**.

Alternatively, press **Shift twice** and type **Restore default settings**

Answer (score 3):

check, if this works for you.

File -> Settings -> (type appe in search box) and select Appearance -> Select Intellij from dropdown option of Theme on the right (under UI Options).

Hope this helps someone.