# Automatically switch to replace mode in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 12 for Android Development, and I met a very strange problem. Whenever I open a file or a dialog (such as Logcat). The cursor switch to replace mode automatically, I have to click the INSERT key on keyboard every time to switch back to normal insert mode. 
It's very weird since I haven't met this problem before, even when I'm using Android Studio and IDEA Communication Edition 12.
Could you please help me solve this problem, thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming this only happens with IDEA? not, for example, Notepad or TextEdit. Have you tried resetting the UI? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540295/reset-intellij-ui-to-default

Comment: did you use ideaVim plugin

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem on Intellij IDEA 13.
That happened to me after changing my theme.

I couldn't find how to fix it in Settings.
But I deleted the config file( you have to enter your licence key again after removing it ),
then changed my theme again.

Now, it works perfect.