# How to reset IntelliJ IDEA Settings?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings

How can I reset the Setting of IntelliJ IDEA? I want to have everything back to the default settings.

Comment: Delete the hidden intellij folder in your home folder. (Probably Documents folder under Windows)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deleting the `config` folder reset my IntelliJ to it's default settings. Mine was located at `C:\Users\BradTurek\.IdeaIC2016.3\config`

[image: IntelliJ Folder Locations]

Comment: Or a less destructive and reversible, just rename that `config` folder to something, example `config.edited`. Then it becomes easy to play around and try stuff, keep versions if desired...

Answer (score 15):

Click on

```
File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings...
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Resetting IntelliJ is something that has been tacked here before. I suggest the following reading:

- [Reset IntelliJ UI to Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540295/reset-intellij-ui-to-default)

If however, this is not what you are looking for, you can always have a look on project settings and IDE settings, and you can mess around wit their folders until you get the desired result (usually deleting a settings folders results in a complete reset, but you should always beackup your things first before trying anything !)

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/project-and-ide-settings.html
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

OSX solution

1. go to Library.
2. search vor IntelliJ
3. delete found folders