# Intellij DataGrip - Restore Default Layout Using Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: datagrip, intellij-datagrip

So I did something dumb and hid the `main` menu toolbar in Datagrip (`File, Edit, etc.`) and now I can't get it back.

[image: Screenshot]

I looked at these, but no luck:

[Reset IntelliJ UI to Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540295/reset-intellij-ui-to-default)

I can't locate the specified `config` directory anywhere.  I also tried the F12 shortcut, but that doesn't work.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html

I unhid hidden folders and system files but I still don't see anything here either:

`<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

Any idea how to get my `main` menu back or to reset to the default layout with a keyboard shortcut as I can't locate the config directory?

I'm using Datagrip 2019.2.5.

Answer (score 3):

I sent a note to support and here's what they said:

> Please use Help | Find Action, type "Main menu.." and toggle it to
>   bring it back.

I couldn't access the main menu, but I used the keyboard shortcut for the Action Finder (Ctrl-Shift-A) and then searched for "Main menu".

[image]